# The sutta that describes how little suffering there is

Tags: reference-request, sutras, suffering, sutta-reference

I remember reading a sutta where the Buddha compares how much suffering there is, or grief or pain or whatever, as if it were a grain of sand, or a bit of dirt on the ground, compared to all the grains of sand in the ganges river or all the mud or something kind of quantitative imagery like that.

I think his point was a bit like that of the metaphor of the Second Arrow; that there might well be some kind of pain, but then all the rest of the torment is fabricated by the deluded mind through reactivity-obsession or passion-obsession and whatnot. This sutta didn't quote that one, but it had the same tenor: 'you won't believe how little there is to worry about.'

I've tried googling for this sutta but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the suttas under [SN 13](https://suttacentral.net/sn13-abhisamayavagga?view=normal).

They talk about how little suffering is left for a stream enterer.

> Then the Buddha, picking up a little bit of dirt under his fingernail,
> addressed the mendicants: “What do you think, mendicants? Which is
> more: the little bit of dirt under my fingernail, or this great
> earth?”
>
> “Sir, the great earth is far more. The little bit of dirt under your
> fingernail is tiny. Compared to the great earth, it’s not nearly a
> hundredth, a thousandth, or a hundred thousandth part.”
>
> “In the same way, for a noble disciple accomplished in view, a person
> with comprehension, the suffering that’s over and done with is more,
> what’s left is tiny. Compared to the mass of suffering in the past
> that’s over and done with, it’s not nearly a hundredth, a thousandth,
> or a hundred thousandth part, since there are at most seven more
> lives. That’s how very beneficial it is to comprehend the teaching and
> gain the vision of the teaching.”.
> [SN 13.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn13.1/en/sujato?layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)

Comment: That's the one! Thanks :)

Comment: Out of interest how did you find this so quickly? From memory or smart searching?

Comment: @yellow-saint Please see the rest of the suttas under [SN 13](https://suttacentral.net/sn13-abhisamayavagga?view=normal). They are all very similar. I remembered the fingernail analogy, so I googled "fingernail sutta".

Comment: Where does the Pali for this sutta include a Pali equivalent for the translation "lives"?

Answer (score 1):

It might be this Mahayana text called the Diamond Sutra. It's an absolute gem of a Sutra to study!

> Diamond Sutra: Chapter 11
>
> “Subhuti, if there were as many Ganges rivers as the
> number of grains of sand in the Ganges, would you say that the number
> of grains of sand in all those Ganges rivers would be very many?”
>
> Subhuti answered, “Very many indeed, Most Honored One. If the number
> of Ganges rivers were that large, how much more so would be the number
> of grains of sand in all those Ganges rivers.”
>
> “Subhuti, I will declare a truth to you. If a good man or a good woman
> filled over ten thousand galaxies of worlds with the seven treasures
> for each grain of sand in all those Ganges rivers, and gave it all
> away for the purpose of compassion, charity and giving alms, would
> this man or woman not gain great merit and spread much happiness?”
>
> Subhuti replied, “Very much so, Most Honored One.”
>
> “Subhuti, if after studying and observing even a single stanza of this
> Sutra, another person were to explain it to others, the happiness and
> merit that would result from this virtuous act would be far greater.”

Comment: Not the one, but upvoting because I was looking through the Diamond Sutra looking for my specific search query to no avail, but really appreciated the revisit nonetheless and can't recommend it enough.